# jade/pug select form javascript onchange event

Tags: javascript, forms, pug

With a select form in Jade, I would like to run a javascript script when the selected is changed. This is my jade file:

```
block content

  script(type='text/javascript' src="../static/js/form.js")

  label(for="category") Category
  select(name="category").form-control
    option(value="") -- Select Category --
    option(value="trees") Trees
    option(value="fruit") Fruit
    option(value="cars") Cars
```

And this is my simple javascript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('category').change(function (e) {
        var value = $('category').val();
        console.log(value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Fix with this:

```
$(function() {
    $('select[name="category"]').change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        console.log($this.val());
    });
});
```

and better put that js file to bottom of body to prevent unpredictable situations when some part is loaded before the code and etc.